# Content query web part not updating

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, publishing-site, content-query-web-part

I built a content by query web part programmatically. The problem is that when I deploy the solution, the web part doesn't update the items automatically. I must go to "edit webpart" and just push <kbd>ok</kbd>, nothing more. Then it updates and I can see my items. I have tried using `UseCatch = false`, as you can see in my code below, but it's not working:

```
public void contentQuery(SPWeb web, SPList list)
{
    ContentByQueryWebPart queryWP = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
    //Properties
    queryWP.Title = "Aktuella Dokument";
    queryWP.ChromeType = PartChromeType.TitleAndBorder;

    //Query from list
    queryWP.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
    queryWP.ListGuid = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
    queryWP.WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl;

    //Query field
    SPField fieldToQuery = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Aktuellt");
    string fieldAsString = fieldToQuery.ToString();
    string FieldValue = fieldToQuery.DefaultValue;

    //queryWP.ListsOverride = fieldAsString;
    queryWP.AdditionalFilterFields = fieldAsString;
    queryWP.FilterField1 = fieldAsString; 
    queryWP.FilterOperator1 = ContentByQueryWebPart.FilterFieldQueryOperator.Eq;  
    queryWP.FilterValue1 = FieldValue;
    queryWP.InitialAsyncDataFetch = true;

    queryWP.UseCache = false;

    AddWebPart(queryWP, web, "TopColumnZone", 0);
}
```